# Need help on proper circuit connection

Tags: msp430, opto-isolator, igbt

I am trying to test IGBT switching using the following circuit but the IGBT smoked out. I am using MSP430 with g2553 chip, NMK0505SAC dc-dc converter, FOD3184 optocoupler and IRG4BC20UD. Please help me if you find anything wrong with my circuit connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The FOD3184 needs a power supply of at least 13.5V (15V~30V recommended) and the IRG4BC20UD needs 15V Gate drive to turn on fully, but the NMK0505SAC dc-dc converter only puts out 5V. You should be using a 5 to 15 Volt DC-DC converter (eg. NMK0515SAC).

Comment: Oh Sorry! Actually I am using NMK0515SAC but it is not working. In fact, I smoked out my IGBT. Please help.

Comment: Apart from the DC-DC converter designation your circuit diagram looks correct, and the IGBT shouldn't be able to 'smoke out' when it has a 50 Ohm resistor on the Gate and 1K on the Collector. Perhaps the physical circuit connections don't match your diagram?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I changed my dc-dc converter to (NME0515SC ) which is not giving me 15 v, Maybe because the datasheet has an inductor order part and maybe I am not loading it in it's 10% of the rated load which is a must. I am not getting anything out from the output of the optocoupler.

Comment: I think as I am giving around 2.7 v in the input of the optocoupler at pin 2 from the MSP430, do I need to use a BJT to supply the base and get it working? I found the IGBT/MOSFET Gate Drive Optocoupler that they have a transistor in the input. I have checked my connections and they seem to be ok to me now but still not getting anything. Would you suggest me to change the optocoupler?

Comment: NME0515SC Link: [link](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/506705/MURATA/NME0515SC.html)
Optocoupler Link: [link](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81227/81227.pdf)
IGBT Link: [link](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irg4bc20ud.pdf)

Comment: 2.7V should be enough. The LED in the opto-coupler should drop about 1.4V and you have a 90 Ohm resistor in series, which equates to 14mA. Recommended LED current is 10~16mA. If the opto-coupler input is dropping 1.1~1.8V between Anode and Cathode and has +15V from Vdd to Vss, but not producing any output (with the IGBT Gate disconnected) then it must be faulty.

Comment: The MSP430 is supposed to generate around 2.7V at the output pin but I found that it is producing 1.8V at the output pin. But the MSP430 datasheet says I should get 2.7V. How to solve this prob?

Comment: Measure the current going into the opto-coupler LED, or measure the voltage across the 90 Ohm resistor and calculate the current. If it is 10mA or higher then the MSP430 is working OK. Also measure the voltage across the LED - it should be between 1.1 and 1.8V (typically 1.4V).